# Lazy loaded component inside lazy loaded component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lazy-loading

Can a lazy loaded component have a lazy loaded component inside it?

Example:

```
const LazyLoaded = lazy(() => import('./path'));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
        <LazyLoaded />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

and `LazyLoaded` component:

```
const LazyChild = lazy(() => import("./another-path"));

const Lazy = () => {
  return (
    <>
      // another markup for example
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Child loading</div>}>
        <LazyChild />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is it possible? This does not seem to be working for me, `LazyChild` is ready whenever the parent is.

Comment: Why do you want to do it ? Lazy load for LazyChild component is redundant action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy components can go in lazy components. I suspect the effect you're observing with React not displaying the fallback for the lazily loaded child is because the DOM updates got batched and the intermediate update that would've shown the fallback for the lazily loaded child got discarded. I've created a demo that shows the fallback for the lazily loaded child given enough time:

1. Press <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd>.
2. The input has been initialised with a `2000` ms delay. You can change it to something else if you'd like.
3. Press <kbd>Render</kbd>.

At this point you can observe all fallbacks being rendered and applied to the DOM. To reset everything press <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> again.

Unfortunately, I can't give more concrete details on exactly why/how the batching is happening. `debugger` statements have been set up in the demo however I don't have time right now to dig into this in more detail. You may do so if you wish.

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { Fragment, StrictMode, Suspense, lazy } = React;

function delay(promise) {
  const time = document.getElementById("delay").value;

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  }).then(() => promise);
}

const LazyChild = lazy(() => {
  debugger;

  return delay(Promise.resolve({
    default: function LazyChild() {
      debugger;

      return <div>LazyChild</div>;
    }
  }));
});

function LazyChildFallback() {
  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} className="fallback">Lazy Child Fallback</div>;
}

const LazyParent = lazy(() => {
  debugger;

  return delay(Promise.resolve({
    default: function LazyParent() {
      debugger;

      return (
        <Fragment>
          <Suspense fallback={<LazyChildFallback />}>
            <LazyChild />
          </Suspense>
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
  }));
});

function LazyParentFallback() {
  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }} className="fallback">Lazy Parent Fallback</div>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Suspense fallback={<LazyParentFallback />}>
        <LazyParent />
      </Suspense>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

let root;
let rootElement;

function render() {
  if (root && rootElement) {
    console.log("Press \"Run code snippet\" button to reset");
    return;
  }
  
  rootElement = document.createElement("div");
  rootElement.setAttribute("id", "root");
  document.body.appendChild(rootElement);
  root = createRoot(rootElement);
  root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
}

document.getElementById("render").addEventListener("click", render);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#root {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.fallback {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input id="delay" name="delay" type="number" value="2000" />
<button id="render">Render</button>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```